# how do you read a file(media) on a users sdcard and display the media on your app (android)

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card, eclipse-adt

I am trying to make an android app that reads a file(that contains only pictures) on the users sdcard and then display it on my app. but I just cant figure out how to call the file and then read it. I have done lots of research and I think I need to somehow use "getExternalStorageDirectory()" but I just cant figure it out.

P.S I am using Eclipse with adt plugin

Comment: will that open that file or replace it

Comment: And how can i make it that it runs this when the activity starts